# CUDA - CUDA Driver is insufficient for CUDA runtime version 6.0

Tags: cuda, driver, nvidia

Previously I have Cuda 5.0 with NVIDIA driver 3.13 install in a Linux ARM computer.

After that I upgrade my Cuda version to 6.0. Anytime, I tried to run any Cuda program I got "Cuda driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version" error.

Then I search for and upgrade my NVIDIA driver to 3.58 (which I think is the latest) and still got the same error.

I'm not sure of any way to overcome this. Or can I check if the old NVIDIA driver still has something to do with this?

Comment: It seems that driver is incompatible with your CUDA version. What is your NVIDIA chip? Why do you prefer 6.0 version (the latest one is 7.5)? Are you sure that you use the latest driver?

Comment: @avtomaton I want to have native CUDA for ARM computer (I believe newer version only support cross-compiling).
Anyway, I use 3.52 and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 3.58 is incompatible with CUDA 6.0. I downgraded it to 3.52 and now it works.